# Do I have to open couchbase port range 21100 to 21199?

Tags: couchbase

I'm using couchbase the lastest version.
Must I open port all of range 21100 to 21199?
Do I have any problem to open port only one of them?(ex, 21100 port)
please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to open these ports. They are used by Erlang for the inter-nodes communication.

Comment: Hi, Just thought a link to the docs about this could be great for others: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-bestpractice-secondfirewall.html

Comment: above link is stale. you can find which ports to configure here: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/install-ports.html